# Synthetic variable with PCA

Tags: pca, ranking

I have some variables regarding companies' workers, and I'd like to come up with a way of rankings these companies according to this data.

Say I have the following variables: number of technicians, number of engineers, number of accountants.

One problem that arises when doing PCA is the following: say the loadings for the first component for the variables above mentioned are `-0.5, 0.25, 0.75`, respectively.

A company with 1 of each (workers, this is) would then get a score of `-0.5*1 + 0.25*1 + 0.75*1 = 0.5`.

A company with just one techician would get a score of `-0.5*1 + 0.25*0 + 0.75*0 = -0.5`.

And a company with no employees (for wathever reason -maybe this is not the best example) would get a score of `-0.5*0 + 0.25*0 + 0.75*0 = 0`.

If I were to rank the companies according to their scores, the third company would be "better" than the second one, but this is clearly not true (we value more having an employee than not).

How can I get around this, or what can I do in this scenario?